# How do I create a date string from a date without including any daylight saving?

Tags: objective-c, date, iso8601

```
NSString* dateString = @"2012-04-01T15:37:53Z";

ISO8601DateFormatter *dateFormat = [[ISO8601DateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setIncludeTime:YES];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

NSDate* date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString timeZone:&utcTimeZone];

STAssertEqualObjects([dateFormat stringFromDate:date timeZone:utcTimeZone], dateString, nil, nil);
```

The above test fails with

> '2012-04-01T16:37:53Z' should be equal to '2012-04-01T15:37:53Z'

Not sure why the NSString returned by the stringFromDate:date is 1 hour later since both dates are using UTC.

Comment: Maybe because the category `dateFromString:timeZone:` (or its inverse) is coded wrong?  Or because you used `&utcTimeZone` in one case and `utcTimeZone` in the other?

Comment: Or maybe set dateFormat.defaultTimeZone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [there is a bug](https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter/pull/4) in the #stringFromDate that [has been resolved in a fork](https://github.com/carllindberg/iso-8601-date-formatter/commit/0e355eeb0ddb5397cee9b668193e45069f5c3f43).